# Should new roles be assigned to SYS

Tags: oracle, permissions

Should the user SYS be assigned new roles beside the roles that it has when it was created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internal Oracle users (`SYS`, `SYSTEM` etc) should never be modified in any way, except for password changes.

As far as roles & grants are concerned, `SYS` already has unrestricted access to the entire RDBMS due to the nature of the user.

Comment: Thx for your answer, that was my impression too. But I've encountered the situation where a bunch of applications specific roles are assigned to SYS, to the point of triggering the "ORA-28031: Maximum of 148 enabled roles exceeded" error :-(. Should all "extra"roles granted to SYS should be dropped?

Comment: Yes, drop them. There is zero need for any additional roles to be granted to `SYS`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the role where granted to the SYS user because it created the role. This is a side affect of the CREATE ROLE statement.

[SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01311)

> If you create a role that is NOT IDENTIFIED or is IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY or BY password, then Oracle Database grants you the role with ADMIN OPTION.

So you can safely revoke the role from the SYS user, as @Phil already wrote.

Comment: Thx, your answer helped me a lot in understanding how the CREATE ROLE command functions.